# GDB: Break on func1 only if previous break was on func2

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have two functions, `func1` and `func2`, each with a breakpoint set.

Is it possible to have GDB stop on the `func2` breakpoint iff the previous breakpoint hit was `func1`?

Comment: Do you have a small code snippet that would demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's no need for a code snippet; the question is crystal clear.

Comment: Breakpoint command lists are your friends. You can give the breakpoint of `func1` the command to set the breakpoint for `func2` iff your program stops due to the first breakpoint.  http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_35.html#SEC35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use commands in breakpoints.

You can direct GDB to execute certain commands (like, to increment a counter) when the two breakpoints are hit. The execution is halted conditionally based on the count of these variables/flags.

I found this information on [this link](http://blog.timac.org/?p=118). Please refer the same for further details. The article is very well-written with proper examples. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have one breakpoint set the other breakpoint. To avoid gdb spaghetti use of `define` to create functions is recommended.

## main.cpp

```cpp
int c1=0, c2=0;

void func1(){
    c1++;
}

void func2(){
    c2++;
}

int main(){

    // we shouldn't see a breakpoint here
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        func1();

    func2();

    // get a breakpoint
    func1();

    return 0;
}
```

## compile and run gdb

```sh
clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -g
gdb --args ./main.exe
```

## gdb commands

```
break func2
commands
    break func1
    # run a few commands when we hit func1()
    commands
    print c1
    backtrace
    end
    # continue to func1() breakpoint
    continue
end
run
```